# Ambiguity between declaration , the member is defined more than once

Tags: java, asp.net, vb.net, web-services, c#-4.0

All the textboxes shows Ambiguity error of duplicate declaration.

```
    txtWebsite.Text = result.website;
                    txtMgrEmail.Text = result.email;
                    txtToEmail.Text = result.email;
                    txtToMgrEmail.Text = result.email;
                    txtFax.Text = result.fax;
                    txtAddress.Text = result.address;
                    txtCity.Text = result.city;
                    txtState.Text = result.state;
                    txtZipCode.Text = result.zip;
                    txtNotes.Text = result.pnote;
                    if (txtMgrEmail.Text == "")
                    {
                        divEmailHistory.Visible = false;
                        gvwEmailHistory.Visible = false;
                    }
```

I have generated designer file again but still and error is not resolved

```
   Error 249 Ambiguity between 'MyCityEats.add_rel_man.gvwEmailHistory' and 'MyCityEats.add_rel_man.gvwEmailHistory'

   Error    226 Ambiguity between 'MyCityEats.admin.add_rel_man.btnCall1' and 'MyCityEats.admin.add_rel_man.btnCall1'
```

similar errors for all the declarations

text box declaration:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNotes" runat="server" Width="343px" Height="80px" 
TextMode="MultiLine" onchange="Javascript:saveMyValue('txtNotes');" 
MaxLength="1000"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: These are assignments. How are these text boxes declared?

Comment: as an id example 
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNotes" runat="server" Width="343px" Height="80px" TextMode="MultiLine"
                                        onchange="Javascript:saveMyValue('txtNotes');" MaxLength="1000"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: This code should go to the post as an edit, don't post it in comments. And the error says that you have one more declaration with the same id, either in markup or in code behind - search for that.

Comment: Actually you said that error is about checkboxes, but what you posted talks about `gvwEmailHistory` (GridView?) and `btnCall1` (Button?)

Comment: I have total 127 errors in my project and the above is only example but all errors are of same type as defined..i am picking up  txtNotes.Text = result.pnote; to proceed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Delete temporary files from location.
   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files (choose correct version of framework).. May require app pool/iis reset to delete files.
2. Close all open files in Visual Studio but don't close solution.
3. Clean solution by right click and selecting clean solution.
4. Build it again. Hopefully you should be good.

Comment: also duplicate class declaration